# SwiftUI Image causing abort trap 6

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When I run the following code I just get one error: ***abort trap: 6***. Anyone have any idea? I already tried deleting the derived data file.

```
class ImageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage = nil
    let session = URLSession.shared

    func loadImage() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ImageViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: viewModel.image)
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
//        Text("hi")
    }

    func loadImage() {
        viewModel.loadImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing Image with a non-nil UIImage, see if the error disappears ?

Answer (score 0):

No worries, it was because of this:

```
var image: UIImage = nil
```

And because I didn't add:

```
.resume()
```